# multiple if statements into better structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

```
list.forEach(el, i) {
  var isTrue = true;
  if (isTrue && i == 0) {
    ary[0] = obj.innerText;
  }
  if (isTrue && i == 1) {
    ary[0] = obj.closest(list[0]).innerText;
    ary[1] = obj.innerText;
  }
  if (isTrue && i == 2) {
    ary[0] = obj.closest(list[0]).innerText;
    ary[1] = obj.closest(list[1]).innerText;
    ary[2] = obj.innerText;
  }
  //same pattern continues up to dozens of if statements
})
```

Hi,
I'm new to JS programming.
list contains css selectors.
obj is DOM element.
How can I improve this code?

Comment: Under what condition is *isTrue* set to false? If never, then it's a useless variable.

Answer (score 1):

All the `if` statements look superfluous and repetitive - why not just do it all at once? Extract all `.textContent` from the matching elements, then put the `obj.textContent` at the end.

```
const ary = Array.from(
  { length: i - 1 },
  (_, i) => obj.closest(list[i]).textContent
).concat(obj.textContent);
```

You [almost certainly want `.textContent`](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/), not `.innerText`.

If the `list` may not contain the same number of elements as the number of `i` conditions you have, just slice the array to the desired length before concating on the final `obj.textContent`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the value of *isTrue* doesn't change, the body can be:

```
ary[i] = obj.textContent;
while (i--) {
  ary[i] = obj.closest(list[i]).textContent;
}
```

You likely don't need the *forEach* loop either, just initialise *i* to *ary.length - 1*.